# Tool for moving website to staging/production server

Tags: php, mysql, deployment

Is there a tool for 'one click' site migration from one server to another?  I develop websites with PHP and MySQL so I need to sync files and databases for each project.  Ideally, I would click "publish" or something and the tool would publish my project on the dev server to the staging server, database and all.

Comment: jenkins build server with some ant scripts that control ftp and some svn..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Documentation-v2.x) is your answer. It's a deployment library written in Ruby, with very few dependencies, that can be used for php also.

It's a bit complicated to set-up, but after that you can just deploy your project with 'one click'.

I doubt there is any simpler way to do that.